# How to remove space before logo in sharepoint designer 2010 master page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created one masterpage in sp designer 2010.all is well but i couldn't delete the empty space before logo (before header table ). it shows like "td" but didn't show any "td" in source code .

Appreciate if anyone answer.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all click edit, page and check if your space contains empty html elements (p of div) and delete it.
If it is a css style problem, you can click html->edit source in the ribbon, and add correct styles to your page.